# I have an MVC application and I want to store documents in Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I am new to Sharepoint and what it can do. I understand that MVC cannot be used in conjunction with Sharepoint. However given that it is the best place to store documents, is it possible to access those documents in an MVC application?
We have recently started using Sharepoint 2010 and we expect to upgrade to 2013 soon.
In my existing MVC application I want to put in links to documents that are stored in Sharepoint.
In addition I would like to copy documents from the file system and put them into Sharepoint.

Can either of these be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sharepoint client object model/server object model to upload document to sharepoint. Also you can retrieve document from the same.

To upload you can refer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1b0f452-cb0a-490e-aed1-33e290115e69/how-to-upload-files-to-sharepoint-using-c?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: I references are a bit old bu the key point is to use the Client Object Model.